# Azure Topics Getting Set of Rules in a Subscription

Tags: azure, servicebus

I would like to be able to access all of the Rule filters setup on a service bus topic subscription in Azure. Is there a way to do this?

Using the SubscriptionClient, I am able to add and remove rules from the subscription, but what I am ultimately trying to do is determine if a specific rule exists on any of my topic subscriptions, and then add it to one of the subscriptions if I don't find it already created somewhere else. Determining what rules already exist across my subscriptions is the missing piece right now.

Edit:
It appears I could garner this information with some ugly exception handling: 
1. Attempt to remove the rule
2. if it does not throw an MessagingEntityNotFoundException then the subscription contained the Rule. Add it back.
3. Otherwise, the subscription did not contain it and we should look through the other subscriptions.

I'm hoping for a solution that's a bit less hacky.

Comment: You can use the NamespaceManager to get a list of the rules for a subscription: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh293119.aspx

Comment: You can, and should, answer your own question here.